# rails paperclip validate content types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, mime-types, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently working on paperclip + s3 file upload job.

I have listed every possible mime types from a random blog... But as you can see, it is really messy and totally not reusable.

Any clue to clean these up..?

I have looked over adding up lines in mime_types.rb file but don't know how to use them..

Please help me

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  include Authority::Abilities

  belongs_to :consulting
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :file
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => %w(
                                                            audio/basic
                                                            video/msvideo, video/avi, video/x-msvideo
                                                            image/bmp
                                                            application/x-bzip2
                                                            text/css
                                                            application/xml-dtd
                                                            application/msword
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
                                                            application/ecmascript
                                                            application/octet-stream
                                                            image/gif
                                                            application/x-gzip
                                                            application/mac-binhex40
                                                            text/html
                                                            application/java-archive
                                                            image/jpeg
                                                            application/x-javascript
                                                            audio/x-midi
                                                            audio/mpeg
                                                            video/mpeg
                                                            audio/vorbis, application/ogg
                                                            application/pdf
                                                            application/x-perl
                                                            image/png
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
                                                            application/vnd.ms-powerpointtd>
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                            application/postscript
                                                            video/quicktime
                                                            audio/x-pn-realaudio, audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
                                                            audio/x-pn-realaudio, audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
                                                            application/rdf, application/rdf+xml
                                                            application/rtf
                                                            text/sgml
                                                            application/x-stuffit
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide
                                                            image/svg+xml
                                                            application/x-shockwave-flash
                                                            application/x-tar
                                                            application/x-tar
                                                            image/tiff
                                                            text/tab-separated-values
                                                            text/plain
                                                            audio/wav, audio/x-wav
                                                            application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
                                                            application/vnd.ms-excel
                                                            application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
                                                            application/xml
                                                            application/zip, application/x-compressed-zip
                                                         )
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, attributes: :file, less_than: 20.megabytes

end
```

Thank you ahead

Comment: Why don't you just store the array of mime types in a constant?

Comment: would you elaborate please?

Comment: Example: `MIME_TYPES = %w(audio/basic video/msvideo ...)`, then in your `paperclip` options: `content_type: MIME_TYPES`. You can define the constant in your `Board` model or in a separate file.